# Issue with calling attribute value on product view - Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, template

I have two custom product attributes that I'm using in my product page template files. One of them doesn't seem to work and I'm wondering if it's something to do with the attribute code.

The attribute codes are:

- small_promo
- c2c_height_1

This **works**:

```
<?php if ($block->getProduct()->getSmallPromo()): ?>
    <!-- do something -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

This **doesn't work**:

```
<?php if ($block->getProduct()->getC2cHeight1()): ?>
    <!-- do something -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is this bit wrong: *getC2cHeight1* ? Is there another method I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to check c2c_height_1 attribute settings correct set or not

[image]

another method to get attribute value.

template code

```
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();

    $heightattribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('c2c_height_1');                  
    if ($heightattribute) 
    { 
        $C2cHeightValue = $heightattribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        echo $C2cHeightValue;
    } 
?>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Your method worked, thank you.

Comment: Welcome @Jarxberg