# Magento 2.3 How get selected options from custom product attribute to list format?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute, attribute-value

How i can get only selected options from custom multi-select attribute in block?

I used

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

And it is doesn't work

Comment: check this ans https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311747/issue-with-calling-attribute-value-on-product-view-magento-2/311748#311748

Comment: I have checked and it's working. selected options show on frontend

Comment: @Devidas $testValue = $test->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) = false -> for me

Comment: what is your attribute name?

Comment: my attribute name = test

Comment: and also check attribute settings is correct or not https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YKqI.png

Comment: hit indexing command and then check

Comment: @Devidas Thank you very much) the problem was in the attribute settings, you helped me)

Comment: oh that's great

Comment: upvote this answer  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311747/issue-with-calling-attribute-value-on-product-view-magento-2/311748#311748

Comment: @Devidas i upvoted

Comment: Thanks @David Young